# Move file and rename it if exist in folder

Tags: python

I'm trying to move file(s) in a folder, but if this file name exists in dest folder i'd like to rename it like ('name.py(1)') for example.

It's working good for the two first files, but after that it crash, but i don't understand why.

```
import os
import shutil
from airflow import AirflowException


uploadPath  = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/'
dirPath = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/'

# print('coucou')
if(os.listdir(uploadPath)):
    for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):
        if not os.listdir(dirPath):
            shutil.move(uploadPath+files, dirPath+files)
            print('no need to rename, so i moved it ...', files)
        else:
            for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):
                addOne=0
                for dirFile in os.listdir(dirPath):
                    if files in dirFile:
                        newName = os.rename(uploadPath+files, dirPath+files+str(addOne))
                        addOne+=1
                        print('renamed in '+str(newName))
                shutil.move(uploadPath+files, dirPath+files)



else:
    print('No file')
    pass
```

error says:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/coco.py' -> '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/coco.py1'
```

Thx for help :)

Comment: seems that you're renaming the file in the loop, then you're trying to move it again.

Comment: yes that's what i guess, but when it does that? because the first files are renamed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep listing files

```
for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):     <<===== files
        if not os.listdir(dirPath):
            shutil.move(uploadPath+files, dirPath+files)
            print('no need to rename, so i moved it ...', files)
        else:
            for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):    <<===== files again
```

in the second loop you should use another variable name because it 'destroys' the first loop.

os.rename moves and renames simultaniously the file if the dirs are not equal. You don't have to first rename the file and then move it.

Some tips:

You could change variable name 'files' into '**file**'. This makes your code more clear because you iterate one file at a time 'for **file** in os.listdir' from the list.

The module os contains a os.path.exists so you don't have to iterate through the whole directory yourself.

Make and use small functions to simplify your code:

```
# -----------------------------
def make_unique_filename(file_path):
    duplicate_nr = 0
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    while os.path.exists(file_path):
        duplicate_nr += 1
        file_path = f'{base}({duplicate_nr}){extension}'

    return file_path

# -----------------------------
uploadPath  = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/'
dirPath = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/'

# -----------------------------
upload_files = os.listdir(uploadPath)
for upload_file in upload_files:
    upload_file_path = os.path.join(uploadPath, upload_file)
    dir_file_path = os.path.join(dirPath, upload_file)
    dir_file_path = make_unique_filename(dir_file_path)
    os.rename(upload_file_path, dir_file_path)
```

Not tested but I guess you get it working :-))

Comment: It does not work, file is erased, i don't why, because it's checked in make_unique_filename

Comment: upload_file_path = os.path.join(dirPath, upload_file) is ofcourse wrong. Sorry. I'll change it and then it should work.

Comment: last question, why the file copy is copying as a string, file= coco.py, become 'coco(1).py' ? Have an error when i try again " FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/coco(1).py' -> '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/coco(1)(1).py'" –

Comment: Filename(duplicate_nr).ext is the usual way to nr duplicates because it leaves the extension as it is. Your .py file stays a .py file, thati s normally the most convenient. The (1)(1) occurs when you copy a (1) file to a dir where this (1) file already exists. When you copy aaaa.bb multiple times to the same dir you get aaaa(1).bb, aaaa(2).bb etc...  Just play with some simple example dirs to see what happens.

Comment: By the way: file_path = f'{base}{extension}({duplicate_nr})' should rename the file your way if you would like that.

Comment: i've got some errors like this one '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/coco(1).py' -> '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/coco(1)(1).py'" and even if i create another file like 'aa.bb'  i've got an error when it try to rename and copy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209172/discussion-between-mace-and-linebaker).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil
from airflow import AirflowException


uploadPath  = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/00_Loading/'
dirPath = '/apps/manu/80_DATA/04_Other/'

def unique_filename(file):
    duplicate_nr = 0
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    while os.path.exists(file):
        duplicate_nr += 1
        file = f'{base}({duplicate_nr}){extension}'
    return file

if(os.listdir(uploadPath)):
    for files in os.listdir(uploadPath):
        if not os.listdir(dirPath):
            shutil.move(uploadPath+files, dirPath+files)
            print('no need to rename, so i moved it ...', files)
        else:
            if os.listdir(dirPath):
                upload_files= os.listdir(dirPath)
                for upload_file in upload_files:
                    upload_file_path = os.path.join(uploadPath, upload_file)
                    dir_file_path = os.path.join(dirPath, upload_file)
                    dir_file_path = unique_filename(dir_file_path)
                    os.rename(upload_file_path, dir_file_path)
                    print('upld path', upload_file_path)
                    print('dir path', dir_file_path)
                    print('upld file', upload_file)
                    print('dir file', upload_files)

else:
    print('No file')
    pass
```

Comment: upload_files = os.listdir(dirPath)   <<< I guess this must be uploadPath